# Why isn't Gildarts one of the Ten Wizard Saints?

Tags: fairy-tail

He clearly is powerful. Makarov even said that Jura's (One of the 10 Wizard Saints) power was close to Gildarts, which means that Gildarts is more powerful than Jura.

So why isn't he a wizard saint?  Does he have to do something magnificent?  Or is he just not popular enough?

Comment: Good question. I had the same question after Erza herself told she is no match for Gildarts, and she herself so strong.

Comment: First of all, I wouldn't think of the magic council hating fairy tail. I would think of it more like this, my mom (the magic council), being strict on me (fairy tail) because I do many reckless things, which, if not monitored, would mean I am led to do more reckless stuff which could endanger something (but in the anime, a person.) So I would just say that they don't want fairy tail to get into more trouble, which will endanger more people..if you get what I mean.

Comment: Or you could compare the magic council to the government (who ever is in charge of handling the army, navy, etc), and Fairy Tail, as the person who acts like a rogue but for a good reason. The military certainly wouldn't let acting without orders or disobeying orders go. They would punish them while thinking about the innocent lives that person could've taken.

Comment: so anyways, back to Gildarts, I agree he doesn't like to be tied by responsibilities. It even shows up in his love life. And if the magic council had given him the position of the 10 wizard saints, he would've refused. Not to mention they don't want the majority to be in favor of fairy tail too, and they don't want fairy tail to act more reckless than they already do (for reasons stated above).

Answer (score 10):

The Chairman of the Magic Council appoints the wizards to the Ten Wizard Saints. The Magic Council's decisions are not always objectively taken, and sometimes blatantly politically motivated. Many of the Magic Council members have a strong dislike for the Fairy Tail guild. It is likely they did not appoint Gildarts because they did not want two Fairy Tail wizards to hold that title.

Another reason is that Gildarts travels a lot going on long missions, and rarely stays at his own guild for long, while the Magic Council probably did not want such a "nomadic" member on that elite group. Moreover, even if the Magic Council made him that offer, Gildarts himself may have turned it down, seeing how he returned the Fairy Tail guild Master's title saying that he is not suited for it.

Answer (score 5):

It's probably not because he **can't** be a wizard saint. He just doesn't **want to** be one. Gildarts does not like positions of influence (he also rejected Guild master title) And as more often said on the internet

> He's too lazy to get off his ass and fill in an application form.
>   Probably doesn't want it, like he didn't want the guild master title.

Also the title currently does not add up to anything but a famous name. He might not even be able to see the profit of having it

> It is just a title, as far as we know, it doesn't offer anything else other than respect from the masses.

I hope this answers your question

Answer (score 1):

Gildarts, Laxus, Mystogan.
Essentially, you need to have your visible and invisible guild members. Gildarts is invisible, or covert. The idea is not to have him in the spotlight, so that he is not targeted, and remains like an Ace up one's sleeve.

Though this anime shows signs of the "never aging" effect, if it were geared more towards progressing over time, we can already tell by how the characters are scripted that Gildarts mode of protecting the guild - or his role in protecting the guild, is by not being in the forefront. That's what Laxus was for. Fairy Tail already has several S-Class wizards also.

It's likely Gildarts was never nominated for or applied for Wizard Saint. It's also likely that there is an exam/test involved just like the Grand Magic games. More importantly, while Gildarts feigns laziness, it's just a masque for him to be able to handle the more underground obligations of keeping Fairy Tail safe.

Notice how he was shown ???name??? that Laxus father was looking for, but Laxus was not. All part of the progression and the plan.

Comment: So what you're saying is that he was just never known in the wizard world despite his reputation of destruction, in which Magnolia has to change it's geographical location, or it because he never proved himself to be a Wizard Saint

Comment: What I mean is, I doubt you get the title based on reputation, but through a formal process that either Gildarts himself, or Makarov would rather he not go through. The title would grant too much visibility, not just in name but appreance and he could not be covert. Some people may know of him by name, by hearsay but it's not the same as being on a list of the top 10 and being known everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is only one reason behind it.
Gildarts is a free spirit and doesn't want to be bounded by the duties of the Ten Wizard Saints.
For him exploring the world and fulfilling the quests is what defines him.
He loved Natsu and other Fairy Tail members and considered them family but still underwent the long SS rank quests because he think he belongs there.

He is kind of like Goku (who believes fighting is what he's meant for and wanders away from his family for that) and Ging Freeches in HunterxHunter.

Comment: To add to that response, he turned down being guild leader so he can wonder around without responsibility, so no way he would get into the politics and responsibility of being a wizard saint. Further more not only does he wonder around, half the time no one knows where he is.  Who knows maybe he was even offered the position and turned it down some time in the past. Wouldn't surprise me.

Answer (score 1):

Gildarts usually would destroy everything in his path by accident. Just look back to the chapter when he comes back to town; they had to rearrange the whole city just to make sure that he did not destroy everything in his path by accidentally tripping or something. Plus, as other have mentioned, Fairy Tail was always known for being a destructive guild.

Answer (score 1):

Nobody would want someone who destroys everything he passes by be called a wizard SAINT. xD He might be strong but reputation-wise, he is just a dirty old skirt chaser who brings literal destruction to those he comes near to.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a speculation, but I think that no sane Magic Council member would make somebody a Wizard Saint who just goes around places destroying everything he touches just because he doesn't pay attention and his magic is still active. (Note that Magnolia has Gildarts-shift for the very same reason.)

Answer (score 0):

1. The council hates Fairy Tail and are responsible for picking the Wizard Saints. There is no reason they would ever pick someone from the guild they hate so much.
2. Gildarts is lazy as hell and dissapears for years at a time to do 100-Year Quests.
3. His power is far too destructive.

Comment: 1. Makarov? 2. Makarov disappeared for 7 years and he is still a Wizard saint. 3. What about Jellal's powers? Jose's powers? Powers are destructive. Greater powers are even more so.

Comment: Jose, Jellal´s clone and Makarov all have control over their powers. If they touch a wall, it´s safe. If Gildarts touches a wall, its gone. His powers are uncontrolable.

Comment: It's not his power that is uncontrollable, it's him who doesn't care enough to control his powers.

Comment: ဲJellal's clone mean mystogan ???

Answer (score 0):

I guess something special is planned for Gildarts:

1. To save the guild from Acnologia, Mavis Vermillion herself had to appear, since the guild was not powerful enough. But Gildarts once encountered Acnologia before and survived losing only some of his organs. How did he do it?
2. He even told Byro of legion that he didn't want the others (guild members & the new Oración Seis) to see what he was really capable of.

So... I guess you get what I'm getting at.

Comment: You can't use Byro as reference since the episode he appears in is Anime exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Gildarts could be a wizard saint. It is possible. Maybe people who read the manga know if he a saint. You never know because the other saints or unknown and in the anime after the s class arc where they return after 7 years he has vanished.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we are all wrong, and he is actually the 2nd strongest wizard saint. We don't know who the top two are, and since the third one's identity is unknown, it is possible for the other two to be unknown.

At the Magic Games, the top three were noted as being "not human" in terms of strength, and, if I remember correctly, Gildarts has been called such on several occasions. So, I believe this theory is probable and the reason I say number two is due to the fact you can't have the top dog not face Natsu and/or Laxus.

Answer (score 0):

The magic council doesn't know Gildarts power level as shown in s-class magic arc. it was when Lohar know about Bluenote Stinger is fighting fairy tail. he say no one in fairy tail strong enough to defeat him. Then I see that Gildarts is stronger than Makarov.